Why does a native English speaker on TV respond "Five month" instead of "5 months" in the context of pregnancy?
Man and his ex-girlfriend are arguing, and the man is shocked to find out his ex-girlfriend is pregnant. And they are talking:

Man: How... I mean, how far gone are you?
Woman: Is it too late to make it go away?
Man: I'm just wondering how...I... if... it...
Woman: Five month.
Man: Five months?
(HE SIGHS)
Man: Have you told anyone about it?
Woman: I haven't got anyone else to tell. That's a relief (!)
Man: No, I... So, how come you've let it get this far? I mean, I thought you might not have wanted to keep it, considering what you've said about how you felt about me.

…British Soap Opera - Coronation Street (see:1:48-1:54) (I checked the subtitles, too.)
Why does the woman say "Five month" when her boyfriend says "Five months"?

As has been explained before, the characters in this soap mostly speak very colloquially in a northern English dialect. There is no particular significance in the fact that she leaves off the 's' and he doesn't.

"How far along are you?" is the American English version of the question, but it has no negative connotations.   "gone" seems to have some, at least to my AmE ear.  Is that form of the question used when the baby is unwanted and/or unexpected?

@TimR - Not in British English. Oxford has -  INFORMAL - having reached a specified time in a pregnancy. "she is now four months gone"

Leaving off the plural 's' is very common in many UK regional dialects, perhaps more in the North: five ton of coal, my meal cost ten pound, I've lived here eight year.

@MichaelHarvey, Thanks Michael, I didn't know that. I am glad I have learnt yet another thing, which I like.

[correction: Why does one native speaker say x]. That is a basic way to ask a question.

@MichaelHarvey, ...reconsider my acceptance of what?


Man, when arguing with his girl friend, is shocked to find out his ex-girl friend is pregnant.

The passage isn’t quite clear.  The girlfriend is the one the man is arguing with.

... how far gone are you?

The person said to be pregnant is his ex-girlfriend.  We leave this part aside.
We should say five months.
Edit
However, as commented,

the characters in this soap mostly speak very colloquially in a northern English dialect

Hence there is no particular significance in that missing ‘s’.

Thanks a lot, @Kate Bunting.  I’ve edited my answer.
